# Не работает bootstrap на nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, bootstrap, nginx

Кладу в папку с сайтом все нужный файлы и index.php в итоге рисует мне страничку, но без стилей....вот файл конфигурации nginx. 
Возможно что-то у меня с location?

```
server {
listen  80;


root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000; 
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}}
```

Мой файл

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Small Business - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/small-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&text=Logo" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Heading Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="">
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h1>Business Name or Tagline</h1>
            <p>This is a template that is great for small businesses. It doesn't have too much fancy flare to it, but it makes a great use of the standard Bootstrap core components. Feel free to use this template for any project you want!</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Call to Action!</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <hr>

    <!-- Call to Action Well -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="well text-center">
                This is a well that is a great spot for a business tagline or phone number for easy access!
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Content Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe rem nisi accusamus error velit animi non ipsa placeat. Recusandae, suscipit, soluta quibusdam accusamus a veniam quaerat eveniet eligendi dolor consectetur.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">More Info</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe rem nisi accusamus error velit animi non ipsa placeat. Recusandae, suscipit, soluta quibusdam accusamus a veniam quaerat eveniet eligendi dolor consectetur.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">More Info</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading 3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe rem nisi accusamus error velit animi non ipsa placeat. Recusandae, suscipit, soluta quibusdam accusamus a veniam quaerat eveniet eligendi dolor consectetur.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">More Info</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А ваш `html` или `php` посмотреть можно? Может у вас там ничего нет...

Comment: Без стилей обычно рисует когда статик файлы не прописаны в location. Нужно посмотерть в консоль браузера и увидеть наличие/отстутствие 404 на статик файлы.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич как прописать правильно location?

Comment: @Klimenkomud добавил в топик index.php мой

Comment: [https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/] тут

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич а если я все файлы закину в общую папку не нужно будет прописывать location? тут много опций я не пойму как его прописывать. у меня есть три папки css,js,fonts они лежат у меня в корне сайта.

Comment: Закинуть в общую можно, но это нарушит структуру сайта, приведет к необходимости правки шаблонов. Не очень хорошее решение. Очень рекомендую научиться работать с location, это гораздо проще чем править шаблоны :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич все решилось гораздо проще. Я просто указал не локальные пути, а web :)